# Error downloading and reading Excel file from URL in R

Tags: r, excel

The following code

> library(readxl)
>   url <- "http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data/ie_data.xls"
>   destfile <- "ie_data.xls"
>   download.file(url, destfile)
>   ie_data <- read_xls(destfile, sheet="Data", skip = 7)

produces `Error in sheets_fun(path) : Failed to open ie_data.xls`
One thing that perplexes me is that if goto the URL and download the file manually I can use read_xls to open it.  I think the issue may be with download.file function.

I'd like to be able to read this Excel file directly from the URL or at least download it and read it without doing so manually.  I'm on a Window  x86_64 system using R 3.5.1 and readxl version 1.1.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I still don't know why the code above doesn't work.  Using this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552923/downloading-excel-file-using-r), I find that the following code will work:

```
library(httr)
library(readxl)
url <- "http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data/ie_data.xls"
GET(url, write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xls")))
ie_data <- read_excel(tf, sheet="Data", skip = 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using windows you have to specify binary mode

```
download.file(url, destfile, mode="wb")
```

Comment: For some reason, SO is putting smart quotes in my code. Just use normal quotes

Comment: prbly macOS. you can toggle that off for SO textboxes.