# xlsx file downloaded by download.file does not open

Tags: r, excel, download, xlsx

I am trying to download a xlsx file with download.file (the file happens to be on a Teams link) and while it works and downloads something when I try to look at the file (in R or just double-clicking the file in windows explorer) it fails.

Then I tested it on a dropbox link and failed similarly (code below). Not sure why but I have tried without and explicit mode and with mode="wb".

Example code:

```
download.file(
    url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/9bumheqlbpxygnl/testfile.xlsx?dl=0", 
    destfile = "test.xlsx",
    mode="wb"
)
```

Error I get reading the downloaded file:

```r
> readxl::read_xlsx("test.xlsx")
Error: Evaluation error: zip file 'C:\Users\tam2\Dropbox\Trabalho\CEAUL\COVID19\Projetos\COVIDETECT\dados\test.xlsx' cannot be opened.
```

Can someone help me understand what might be going on? I saw here on StackOverflow that others solved their problem by using `mode="wb"`, but that has no impact here (does not work in either mode).

The above link does have a file for testing in case you want to use it. Many thanks

I also tried a variant I found here

[Error downloading and reading Excel file from URL in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330861/error-downloading-and-reading-excel-file-from-url-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

based on

```r
library(httr)
GET("https://www.dropbox.com/s/9bumheqlbpxygnl/testfile.xlsx?dl=0", write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xls")))
data <- read_excel(tf)
```

but again hit a stone wall

```r
Error: 
  filepath: C:\Users\tam2\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCA2uEa\file31802e134f09.xls
  libxls error: Unable to open file
```

```r
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Comment: You downloaded the file to whatever was you working directory might have been at the time but I’m guessing not the one you thought it was.  Use ‘getwd()’

Comment: I think your URL is wrong; that's a link to a Dropbox page about the file, not to the file itself.

Comment: I think the local path was not the problem, I was actually pointing to the right path and read_xlsx was just not being able to process the file - probably because @alistaire was right (it was not an excel file that had been downloaded, so it would not recognize it, even though it was called the right thing since the name of the file was correct). I was not aware of the difference between dl=0 and dl=1 in dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Both comments to the question solve the problem on my pc.

```
url <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/9bumheqlbpxygnl/testfile.xlsx?dl=1"
fn <- tempfile(fileext=".xlsx")
download.file(url, destfile=fn, mode="wb")
library(readxl)
dat <- read_excel(fn)
str(dat)
```

Note that the url is changed to `dl=1` and that a full path is provided to `download.file` and `read_excel`. It seems that `download.file` writes by default in the `~/Downloads` folder at least here on my windows pc.

The other approach works as well:

```
library(httr)
GET(url, write_disk(fn, overwrite=TRUE))
dat <- read_excel(fn)
```

Note that `data` is also a base R function, hence it is not a good idea to name a variable with that name.

Comment: Many thanks, the dl=1 vs dl=0 solved it. I was not aware of this difference. The "dl=0" version was what I got in dropbox by doing the "copy drobox link".  Unfortunately, I suspect this means the link I get in Teams (this was my test file, the real one is in Teams) doing the analogous action also points not to the file itself but a file about the file, so now I need to find out how to change the Teams provided link to the actual file link... anyone knows where I might find about that (thanks for the dat vs data tip !).