# How to download from the URL a .xls data with merged cells using R

Tags: r, excel, download

I've been trying to download a .xls data directly from its URL. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552923/downloading-excel-file-using-r) and the `readHTMLTable` function, but it apparently doesn't work for .xls, only for tables HTML documents.

It kind of worked with:

```r
my_url <- 'https://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Censos/Censo_Demografico_2022/Previa_da_Populacao/POP2022_Brasil_e_UFs.xls'

download.file(url=my_url, fillMergedCells = TRUE, destfile='./df.xlsx')
```

But when I try to open it with:

```r
df <- read_xlsx('./df.xlsx')`
```

I get the following error:

> Error in utils::unzip(zip_path, list = TRUE) :
> zip file ';/df.xlsx' cannot be opened"

My data is not zipped.

Also, I could open the archive on my computer out of R, but it was all messed in another encoding with lots of "??????". I solved this problem with:

```r
download.file(url=my_url, fillMergedCells = TRUE, destfile='./df.xlsx', mode = "wb")
```

But now when I try to read the dataframe it returns the error

> Error: `` not found

I know that there's a way of downloading it directly from the URL and open it properly, but I just can't make it work.

Not sure if that's a relevant information, but the first line of the archive is made from merged cells.

Comment: The current `.xlsx` (including docx, pptx, etc.) format *is* a zipped file using the [Open XML](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml-formats-and-file-name-extensions-5200d93c-3449-4380-8e11-31ef14555b18) standard. But the older `.xls` is a binary file and not a zipped file. These two Excel types are *not* interchangeable.

Comment: Please include all `library` lines or package double colon qualifier references as `read_xlsx` can derive from various third-party packages.

Answer (score 2):

The source file referenced in the url is of type ".xls" but you store it and attempt to process it as an ".xlsx". The xls and xlsx file formats are not the same . You should

```
my_url <- 'https://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Censos/Censo_Demografico_2022/Previa_da_Populacao/POP2022_Brasil_e_UFs.xls' 
download.file(url = my_url, fillMergedCells = TRUE, destfile = './df.xls') 
df <- readxl::read_xls('./df.xls')
```